# Merging and updating hash keys in Redis with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, redis

I have a list the following hashes:

```
{
  key_main1: {
    k1: 1,
    k2: 11,
    k3: 33,
    k4: 146,
    k5: 12,
    # etc
  },

  key_main2: {
    k1: 1,
    k2: 11,
    k3: 33,
    k4: 146,
    k5: 12,
    # etc
  },

  # etc  
}
```

which is save in a redis as json:

```
redis_key1 = "redis_key1"
redis.set("redis_key", my_hash.to_json)
redis.get("redis_key") # =>
"{"key_main":{"k1":1,"k2":11,"k3":33,"k4":146,"k5":12}}"
```

The hashes have the same structure but can have different keys. On each iteration I want to update the existing keys by summing up the values of "k"s or/and insert the keys that don't exist:
So the second hash in the list looks like this

```
{
  key_main1: {
    k3: 44,
    k4: 14,
    k18: 99
  },

  key_main3: {
    k2: 77
  }

}
```

Then after the seconds iteration the result in Redis will look like the following:

```
{
  key_main1: {
    k1: 1,
    k2: 11,
    k3: 33,
    k4: 160,
    k5: 12,
    k18: 99

  },

  key_main2: {
    k1: 1,
    k2: 11,
    k3: 33,
    k4: 146,
    k5: 12
  },

  key_main3: {
    k2: 77
  }
}
```

What's the **easiest** and **best** way to do it? Do I have to parse (restore)json in each iteration in order to check if the keys exist and update or insert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to parse the JSON back into a hash, otherwise you will have a really hard time figuring out how to combine the hashes.

To combine them, the best and easiest is with [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
h1 = { m1: { k1:  10, k2: 20, k3: 30 }, m2: { k1: 11, k2: 12 } }
h2 = { m1: { k1: 500, k2:  5, k4: 40 }, m3: { k2: 123 } }

pp h1.merge(h2) { |key, v1, v2|
   v1.merge(v2) { |key, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
}

=> { :m1 => { :k1 => 510,:k2 => 25, :k3 => 30, :k4 => 40 },
     :m2 => { :k1 => 11, :k2 => 12},
     :m3 => { :k2 => 123 } }
```

This code assumes the keys in `h1` and `h2` always contain a hash with integer keys.

Comment: is `h1.merge(h2)` the same as `h2.merge(h1)`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp yes when you do manual merging in a block it is. Only the order of `v1` and `v2` changes. Without a block Ruby selects `h2` for duplicate keys when you do `h1.merge(h2)`.